# Owned type mapping EF Core fails when saving

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to make TableSplitting using Owned Types. I have the following model:

```
public class Account 
{
  public GUID Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class StreetAddress
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Zipcode { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string  Country { get; set; }
  public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
  public double Lat { get; set; }
  public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

And I defined my mapping of the Account like this:

```
public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> map)
{
    // Keys
    map.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    // Indexs
    map.HasIndex(x => x.Email).IsUnique();

    // Property mappings.
    map.Property(x => x.Email).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();

    // Owned types.
    map.OwnsOne(x => x.Address, cb => cb.OwnsOne(a => a.Location));
}
```

When I run the migration things are working and the columns are created in the database. But when I try to insert and save an address like so:

```
var account1 = new Account("e@mail.com", "First", "Last")
    {
      Address = new StreetAddress()
                  {
                        Address1 = "Street 1",
                        City = "City",
                        Zipcode = "2000",
                        Country = "Denmark",
                        Location = new Location()
                        {
                            Lat = 0.0,
                            Lng = 5.5
                        }

                    }
                };
this.Context.Accounts.Add(account1);
```

I get this error

> Message   "The entity of 'Account' is sharing the table 'Accounts' with
>   'Account.Address#StreetAddress', but there is no entity of this type
>   with the same key value 'Id:b7662057-44c2-4f3f-2cf0-08d504db1849' that
>   has been marked as 'Added'."

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you call the `Map` method shown? Because I'm getting the error in question only if I don't call it.

Comment: @Edit : It should be added by convention, according to the docs. And there should be no need for a primary key as fields should all go in the Account table that has a primary key defined - or do I get this wrong?

Comment: @IvanStoev -> Iam pretty sure - but Ill just make a check to confirm.

Comment: @IvanStoev : You are right - It was never called in the migration flow. What a stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Can't reproduce either - works like a charm (I assume the `Account` constructor sets corresponding properties from arguments and also sets `Id = Guid.NewGuid();`). Probably your real code is different.

Comment: Sorry for being off this question for such a long time - I got the creating part working now, but is there any way an OwnedType can be set as nullable? So its possible to not set any data. i'am getting the same error when not providing a value for the address.

Comment: OwnedType no support for optional (i.e. nullable) owned types that are mapped with the owner in the same table (i.e. using table splitting). I recommend you see this thread https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/466

Comment: @RuneJensen, how did you make it work? I have a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710443/saving-entity-with-owned-property

Comment: Look this documentation: [Owned Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities)

Comment: Suggest that you move Location up to the Account instead of keeping it in Address.

Comment: Please show your database table columns strcuture

Answer (score 1):

Consider using virtual properties. This can also be used for lazy loading in your application

```
 public class Account 
 {
  public GUID Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public virtual StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
 }

public class StreetAddress
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Zipcode { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string  Country { get; set; }
  public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
  public double Lat { get; set; }
  public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add constructors and initialize owned entities.

```
public class Account 
{
  public Account (){
    Address = new StreetAddress();
  }

  public GUID Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class StreetAddress
{
  public StreetAddress(){
    Location = new Location();
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Zipcode { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string  Country { get; set; }
  public Location Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
  public double Lat { get; set; }
  public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

In other words there can't be optional owned entities.

Note: if you have a non-empty constructor you also must add empty constructor due to [ef core limitations.](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12078)

Comment: A constructor isn't necessary if you initialize the property by default e.g. public StreetAddress Address { get; set; } = new StreetAddress();

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Account {
  public GUID Id { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public StreetAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class StreetAddress {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string Zipcode { get; set; }
  public string City { get; set; }
  public string  Country { get; set; }
  public Location[] Location { get; set; }


public class Location {
  public double Lat { get; set; }
  public double Lng { get; set; }
}
```

try this because once you call your object in the shape of all is in relation with Account class but the reality is you don't define that relation which I made

Answer (score 0):

For an Account to be added in the database. It's references should be saved first in the table. For adding data in database it should be in the following order: Location > StreetAddress > Account

Answer (score 0):

I am sure if you try adding every object to the context then build the parent it would work
meaning add the location first and then create address and reference the location object u made
add the address to the context
afterwards create and account and reference the added address in it!

Or you could add ctors to ur models that init new instances of each navigation property

one last thing, this really shouldn't be an issue as of EF Core 5 since it has tons of new bells and whistles when it comes to navigation properties

```cs
public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<Account> map)
{
    // Keys
    map.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    // Indexs
    map.HasIndex(x => x.Email).IsUnique();

    // Property mappings.
    map.Property(x => x.Email).HasMaxLength(255).IsRequired();

    // Owned types.
    map.OwnsOne(x => x.Address, cb => cb.OwnsOne(a => a.Location));
}
```

if you're using it, you really dont need the following part
just add your `DbSet<T>`s appropriately and thats it