# Saving entity with owned property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

Ok, this might be a dumb question, but I can't figure it out (tried searching but with no reasonable effect).

I have a model:

```
public class Freelancer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

which is configured as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address).Property(x => x.Name1).HasColumnName("AddressName1");
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address).Property(x => x.Name2).HasColumnName("AddressName2");
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address).Property(x => x.ZipCode).HasColumnName("AddressZipCode");
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address).Property(x => x.City).HasColumnName("AddressCity");
```

and then I have a method that tries to create new `Freelancer` entity along with it's `Address`:

```
var address = new Address(command.Name1, command.Name2, command.ZipCode, command.City);
var freelancer = new Freelancer();
freelancer.Address = address;
_freelancerRepository.SaveOrUpdate(freelancer);
_freelancerRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Where `SaveOrUpdate` method basically does what `dbContext.Set<Freelancer>().Add(...)` is doing. And `SaveChanges` does exactly what `dbContext.SaveChanges()` is doing.

And now, `SaveChanges` throws an exception that's saying:

> The entity of type 'Address' is sharing the table 'Freelancers' with entities of type 'Freelancer', but there is no entity of this type with the same key value that has been marked as 'Added'.

What do I do wrong?

PS.

I've also tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Freelancer>().OwnsOne(x => x.Address, a => { a.Property(...
```

implementation with exact same results.

Update:
Heres my dbContext class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Freelancer> Freelancers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // configuration as above
    }
}
```

And, that's custom `SaveOrUpdate` implementation:

```
public void SaveOrUpdate(TDatabaseObject obj)
{
    if (_context.Set<TDatabaseObject>().Any(x => x.Id == obj.Id))
    {
        _context.Update(obj);
    }
    else
    {
        _context.Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in what you have shown. The problem is most likely in `SaveOrUpdate` custom method not shown - working with disconnected entities is not easy and details matter. "basically does" is not enough, please show the implementation of that method.

Comment: Can you post the `DbContext class` also with the `DbSets` please?